# Can't override default kwarg value of False in template inclusion tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've written this template inclusion tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/post_detail.html')
def post_detail(post, show_meta=True):
    return {
        'post': post,
        'show_meta': show_meta
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
{% post_detail post show_meta=False %}
```

This works just fine. The template is properly rendered  with `show_meta` having a value of `False`.

But, if I change the default of `show_meta` to be `False` like this:

```
def post_detail(post, show_meta=False):
```

And then if I try to call it with `{% post_detail post show_meta=True %}`, the template is still rendered with `show_meta` having a value of `False`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`True` and `False` are not defined in the template context by default, and by the normal template language rules, non-existent names are treated as False. Try passing 0 and 1 instead.